# Select arrays between date ranges with Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of arrays, I want to select arrays with a date that falls in a certain range.

```
ar = [[72162, "2014-01-21"], 
[53172, "2014-01-22"], 
[49374, "2014-01-23"], 
[41778, "2014-01-24"], 
[34182, "2014-01-25"], 
[58869, "2014-01-26"], 
[72162, "2014-01-27"], 
[43677, "2014-01-28"], 
[37980, "2014-01-29"], 
[87354, "2014-01-30"], 
[43677, "2014-01-31"]]
```

For example, I'd like to get all arrays between `2014-01-24` and `2014-01-29`.

Comment: If any of the answers were of use, consider selecting the one that most helpful to you.

Answer (score 4):

Without using `Date`:

```
ar.select { |_,d| d >= "2014-01-24" && d <= "2014-01-29" }

=> [[41778, "2014-01-24"],
    [34182, "2014-01-25"],
    [58869, "2014-01-26"],
    [72162, "2014-01-27"],
    [43677, "2014-01-28"],
    [37980, "2014-01-29"]]
```

or

```
ar.select { |_,d| ("2014-01-24".."2014-01-29").cover?(d) }
```

Note this depends on the date being expressed in year-month-day order.

Edit: I formerly used what I thought was [Range#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F), but @toro2k pointed out that is was actually [Enumerable#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F), which is quite slow.  I had thought that `Range#include?` would be able to just compare endpoints, since `<=>` is defined for Strings.  Not so; it only applies when the values are numeric or single character strings (else it `super`s to `Enumerable#include?`). That puzzled me.  For anyone interested, I think I now understand the reason for the restricted application.

We would want `('aa'..'zz').include?('mno')` to behave the same as

```
('aa'..'zz').to_a.include?('mno') => false
```

Suppose we do this:

```
class String
  alias :spaceship :<=>
  def <=>(other)
    spaceship(other.size > 1 ? other[0,2] : other)
  end
end
```

Then

```
"mno" >= 'aa' # => true
"mno" <= 'zz' # => true
```

so if `Range#include?` only considered the endpoints,

```
('aa'..'zz').include?("mno") # => true
```

Comment: One of the nice things about ISO 8601 dates is that they compare sensibly as strings.

Comment: @muistooshort this is new to me thanks for the tip, any link to this??

Comment: @bjhaid, I think μ just means that since [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) dates are yyyy-mm-dd, two dates, expressed as strings, can be ordered with `<=>`; that is, yyyy's are compared, if both are the same, mm's are compared, if the same, dd's are compared.

Comment: @bjhaid: Cary's right on that, it even extends to timestamps as all the components are listed in a sensible order &mdash; largest to smallest &mdash; all the way down to the seconds. You still have to normalize the time zones of course.

Comment: @muistooshort and Cary I understand the Comparable spaceship explanation, but I was wondering if there is a reference to the implementation that allows comparison of ISO 8601 as strings

Comment: Using `Range#include?` with strings more than one character long is pretty inefficient since it uses `Enumerable#include?` and have to traverse all the range, thus the wider the range, the slower the test.

Comment: @toro2k, that's [Range#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F), which just compares endpoints. More generally, whenever an Enumerable method would be inefficient for the receiver, look for a method with the same name in the receiver's class. I'm glad you raised this issue. I'll do a small edit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `Range#include?` just compares string endpoints only if they are one character long, please check the [implementation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/range.c#L1152-L1197).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks to you for the explanation! Definetly +1!

Comment: @bjhaid: Just look at the ISO 8601 format and keep in mind that digit characters come in the same order as the numbers.

Comment: @toto2k, I wouldn't have tweaked to that without your probing.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'
range = Date.parse("2014-01-24")..Date.parse("2014-01-29")
ar.select { |x| range.include?(Date.parse(x[1])) }
=> [[41778, "2014-01-24"],
 [34182, "2014-01-25"],
 [58869, "2014-01-26"],
 [72162, "2014-01-27"],
 [43677, "2014-01-28"],
 [37980, "2014-01-29"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`Comparable#between?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F)

```
ar = [ [72162, "2014-01-21"], 
       [53172, "2014-01-22"], 
       [49374, "2014-01-23"], 
       [41778, "2014-01-24"], 
       [34182, "2014-01-25"], 
       [58869, "2014-01-26"], 
       [72162, "2014-01-27"], 
       [43677, "2014-01-28"], 
       [37980, "2014-01-29"], 
       [87354, "2014-01-30"], 
       [43677, "2014-01-31"]
     ]

ar.select { |_,e| e.between?("2014-01-24","2014-01-29") }
# => [[41778, "2014-01-24"],
#     [34182, "2014-01-25"],
#     [58869, "2014-01-26"],
#     [72162, "2014-01-27"],
#     [43677, "2014-01-28"],
#     [37980, "2014-01-29"]]
```