# Combining multiple array/hash selects

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have the following code:

```
sum = array_of_hashes.select{ |key| (date_range).include? Date.parse(key[:created])}.map { |h| h[:amount] }.sum 
size = array_of_hashes.select{ |key| (date_range).include? Date.parse(key[:created])}.size
total = sum / size
```

`sum` selects all hashes with a date that is inside a date range and the adds up all the values of the `:amount` key.

`size` counts the number of hashes that are in the date range.

`total` divides the `sum` by the `size`.

How can I combine those so it's not 3 separate items?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's as simple as:

```
selected = array_of_hashes.select { ... }
avarage = selected.map { ... }.sum / selected.size
```

**Note**: using `include?` with ranges of dates is pretty inefficient since it needs to traverse the whole dates range, I suggest to use `cover?` instead.

Comment: Do you know of a way to do that in one line (even if it sacrifices a little bit of readability)?

Comment: Why do you want it on one line?

Comment: Asking if it's possible. I you can't do it, no worries. Curious if it can be done, though.

Comment: For sure it is possible, just put a semicolon between the two lines! :-)

Comment: @sawa Nothing to be sorry about! :-) `cover?` and `include?` behaves almost the same when endpoints are `Numeric`s or `String`s of size 1, in any other case `include?` calls `Enumerable#include?`. In [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507117/select-arrays-between-date-ranges-with-ruby/21507252#21507252) you can find more information.

Comment: @toro2k But the [C source code](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) shows that it is indeed `Range#include?`. Or, is it this line: `return rb_call_super(1, &val);` that calls `Enumerable#include?`?

Comment: @sawa Yes, `rb_call_super` in C is, roughly, `super` in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no nice way of doing this more compact. One alternative could be the following:

```
average = (selected = array_of_hashes.select { ... }.map { ... }).sum/selected.size.to_f
```