# What is the difference between `Range#include?` and `Range#cover?`?

Tags: ruby, range

**Edit** Fixed following toro2k's comment.

`Range#include?` and `Range#cover?` seem to be different as seen in the source code [1](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F), [2](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F), and they are different in efficiency.

```
t = Time.now
500000.times do
    ("a".."z").include?("g")
end
puts Time.now - t    # => 0.504382493

t = Time.now
500000.times do
    ("a".."z").cover?("g")
end
puts Time.now - t    # => 0.454867868
```

Looking at the source code, `Range#include?` seems to be more complex than `Range#cover?`. Why can't `Range#include?` be simply an alias of `Range#cover?` What is their difference?

Comment: I too was puzzled by that.  See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507117/select-arrays-between-date-ranges-with-ruby/21507252#21507252).

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The two methods are designed to do two slightly different things on purpose. Internally they are implemented very differently too. You can take a look at the sources in the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) and see that `.include?` is doing a lot more than `.cover?`

The `.cover?` method is related to the `Comparable` module, and checks whether an item would fit between the end points in a sorted list. It will return true even if the item is not in the set implied by the `Range`.

The `.include?` method is related to the `Enumerable` module, and checks whether an item is actually in the complete set implied by the `Range`. There is some finessing with numerics - Integer ranges are counted as including all the implied `Float` values (I'm not sure why).

These examples might help:

```
('a'..'z').cover?('yellow')
# => true

('a'..'z').include?('yellow')
# => false

('yellaa'..'yellzz').include?('yellow')
 => true
```

Additionally, if you try

```
('aaaaaa'..'zzzzzz').include?('yellow')
```

you should notice it takes a *much* longer time than

```
('aaaaaa'..'zzzzzz').cover?('yellow')
```

Comment: I see. So now it looks to me that `Range#include?` is very mysterious.

Comment: You weren't kidding, `('aaaaaa'..'zzzzzz').include?('yellow')` takes minutes to run!

Answer (score 14):

The main difference is that `include` is checking whether object is one of range element, and cover is returning whether object is between edge elements. You can see that:

```
('a'..'z').include?('cc')     #=> false
('a'..'z').cover?('cc')       #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date_range = {:start_date => (DateTime.now + 1.days).to_date, :end_date => (DateTime.now + 10.days).to_date}                
date_range_to_check_for_coverage = {:start_date => (DateTime.now + 5.days).to_date, :end_date => (DateTime.now + 7.days).to_date}                

(date_range[:start_date]..date_range[:end_date]).include?((DateTime.now + 5.days).to_date)                
#true        
(date_range[:start_date]..date_range[:end_date]).cover?((DateTime.now + 5.days).to_date)                
#true        
(date_range[:start_date]..date_range[:end_date]).include?(date_range_to_check_for_coverage[:start_date]..date_range_to_check_for_coverage[:end_date])                
#true        
(date_range[:start_date]..date_range[:end_date]).cover?(date_range_to_check_for_coverage[:start_date]..date_range_to_check_for_coverage[:end_date])                
#false
```

Shouldn't the last line return true ?

The reason I am asking is rubocop flags a conflict when I use include? in place of cover?. And clearly, my logic (to check if the range is included in another range) does not work with cover?.

Answer (score 0):

## There's a huge performance difference between `cover?` and `include?`: special care when using Date ranges

For the reasons already explained: `cover?` just checks if your argument is between the begin and the end of the range; in `include?`, you are checking if your argument **is** actually inside the range, which involves checking *every single element of the range*, and not just the begin/end.

Let's run a simple benchmark.

```rb
date_range = Date.parse("1990-01-01")..Date.parse("2023-01-01");

target_date = Date.parse("2023-01-01"); 

iterations = 1000;

Benchmark.bmbm do |bm|

  bm.report("using include") { iterations.times { date_range.include?(target_date) } }

  bm.report("using cover") { iterations.times { date_range.cover?(target_date) } }

end
```

Results:

```
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------------
using include   5.466448   0.071381   5.537829 (  5.578123)
using cover     0.000272   0.000003   0.000275 (  0.000279)
---------------------------------------- total: 5.538104sec

                    user     system      total        real
using include   5.498635   0.046663   5.545298 (  5.557880)
using cover     0.000284   0.000000   0.000284 (  0.000280)
```

As you can see, using `#cover?` is *instantenous*; you get your results in 0.000ms.

However, using `#include?` takes almost *5.5 seconds* for the same results.

Choose carefully.