# Can we include ranges in .include? ruby

Tags: ruby, range

I am just trying to find whether there is any character included in array. So i just tried to include range in include function which seems not working.

```
if @array.include?('a'..'z') then
  puts "Doesnt have Permutation"
else
  puts "Have permutation"
end
```

Comment: Post input data and expected results

Answer (score 6):

You may need to use [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) for this.

Some examples here about the use of `#grep`.

```
['w', '-', 12].grep('a'..'z') # => ["w"]
[ 4 , :a, '^'].grep('a'..'z') # => []
['w', '-', 'e'].grep('a'..'z') # => ["w", "e"]
```

Here is a modified code of your using `#grep` :

```
ary = ['w', '-', 12]
if ary.grep('a'..'z').empty?
  puts "Doesnt have Permutation"
else
  puts "Have permutation"
end    
# >> Have permutation
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd want

`@array.any? { |c| ('a'..'z').include?(c) }`

if you forgot about `grep`.

Comment: n.b. `cover?` is better than `include?` for `Range`s in 1.9+

Comment: Thanks, @roippi.  I would agree with you that Range#cover? is better than Enumerable#include?, since the latter checks everything in the range.  However, when `include?`'s argument is a Fixnum or a single character (as here), Range#include?, which only considers endpoints, is used.  Hence, it doesn't matter.  For more on this, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608935/what-is-the-difference-between-rangeinclude-and-rangecover) posted today and also the link I gave in a comment on the question.