# Shorter ways to write this condition n != 1 && n != 2 && n != 3 && n !=4 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, algorithm, if-statement, operators, conditional-statements

I want to check if the input is one of four numbers 1, 2, 3, 4. If not, there should be an error message. I start out with this

```
n = gets.chomp.to_i
if n != 1 && n != 2 && n != 3 && n != 4
    puts 'invalid input'
end
```

This also happens a lot in other languages. How can I shorten the above condition `n != 1 && n != 2 && n != 3 && n != 4`?

Comment: `[1,2,3,4].include?(n)`

Comment: `n != 1 || n != 2 || n != 3 || n != 4` is always true. Do you mean `n != 1 && n != 2 && n != 3 && n != 4` ?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that. Edited.

Comment: You don't need `chomp` here.

Comment: Could the four numbers have been `1`, `2`, `3`, `5`, or `4`, `3`, `2`, `1`, or do they always constitute a range? If they needn't represent a range you should have used a different example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use [`Range#cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) which might be [faster than `include?`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21609473/2483313):

```
number = gets.chomp.to_i
puts('invalid input') unless (1..4).cover?(number)
```

Comment: Didn't know about `cover?`. So, in this case, `cover?` is doing `n >= 1 && n <= 4` instead of checking every item in the `Range`.

Comment: Exactly. Which makes it much faster for bigger ranges, but might result in unexpected results on string ranges.

Comment: [Range#include?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) is the same as [Range#cover?](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) when, as here, the endpoints are numeric.

Answer (score 5):

Fastest possible check:

```
if n < 1 || n > 4
```

Comment: Probably you mean `n < 1`.

Comment: Yes, for some it might be easier to see !(n >= 1 && n <= 4), then just use De Morgan's laws to get rid of the not and you get the answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's a `case` statement:

```
case num
when 1,2,3,4
  puts "it's ok"
else
  puts "it's not ok"
end
```

For instance:

```
[0, 1, 4, 5].each do |num|
  case num
  when 1,2,3,4
    puts "#{num} is ok"
  else
    puts "#{num} is not ok"
  end
end

# >> 0 is not ok
# >> 1 is ok
# >> 4 is ok
# >> 5 is not ok
```

Or a bit DRYer:

```
[0, 1, 4, 5].each do |num|
  puts case num
       when 1,2,3,4
         "#{num} is ok"
       else
         "#{num} is not ok"
       end
end

# >> 0 is not ok
# >> 1 is ok
# >> 4 is ok
# >> 5 is not ok
```

And, since `when` allows ranges, you could use `when 1 .. 4` instead.

---

While I appreciate the benchmark results showing that using `case` was fastest, it didn't make sense, because Casper's should have been. Here's what I found:

```
require 'fruity'

n = 1
compare do
  casper1 { n < 1 || n > 4 }
  casper2 { n >= 1 && n <= 4 }
  casper3 { 1 <= n && n <= 4 }
  sagarpandya82 {n.between?(1,4)}
  spickerman {(1..4).cover?(n)}
  reitermarkus {[1, 2, 3, 4].include?(n)}
  ttm {case n;when 1,2,3,4;true;else;false;end}
end

# >> Running each test 262144 times. Test will take about 11 seconds.
# >> casper2 is similar to casper3
# >> casper3 is faster than ttm by 2x ± 1.0
# >> ttm is faster than casper1 by 2x ± 1.0 (results differ: true vs false)
# >> casper1 is faster than sagarpandya82 by 3x ± 1.0 (results differ: false vs true)
# >> sagarpandya82 is similar to spickerman
# >> spickerman is faster than reitermarkus by 2x ± 0.1
```

In running that several times `casper2` and `casper3` will alternate being fastest and next fastest, followed by using `case` in `ttm`.

The results will change as more values are added. In particular, I think the `include` and `when 1,2,3,4` tests would be seriously impacted.

Just to show that it's unnecessary to collapse the space, or, said differently, that whitespace doesn't make a difference:

```
require 'fruity'

n = 1
compare do
  ttm1 {case n;when 1,2,3,4;true;else;false;end}
  ttm2 {case n; when 1,2,3,4; true; else; false; end}
  ttm3 {
    case n
        when 1,2,3,4
          true
        else
          false
        end
  }
end

# >> Running each test 131072 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> ttm1 is similar to ttm3
# >> ttm3 is similar to ttm2
```

With Fruity, when you see these sort of "is similar to " results they'll tend to alternate in order because the difference in speed is usually the result of system wobble during testing.

And finally, comparing `when 1,2,3,4` with `when 1..4`:

```
require 'fruity'

n = 1
compare do
  ttm1 {
    case n
    when 1,2,3,4
      true
    else
      false
    end
  }

  ttm2 {
    case n
    when 1..4
      true
    else
      false
    end
  }
end

# >> Running each test 131072 times. Test will take about 2 seconds.
# >> ttm1 is faster than ttm2 by 8x ± 10.0
```

Comment: Strictly speaking shouldn't we say `case expression` instead of `case statement` in Ruby?

Answer (score 2):

I would use a `Range` for this, and an `unless`-statement instead of an `if`:

```
unless (1..4).include?(n)
  puts 'invalid input'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If your range is joint you can use

```
n.between?(1,4)
```

I was curious for the fastest solution and much to my surprise it is the `case` solution, both when `n` in the range and outside, at least on MRI 1.9.3 under Windows 7. The only pitty it is also the longest solution..

```
Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report {r.times {n < 1 || n > 4}}
  x.report {r.times {n.between?(1,4)}}
  x.report {r.times {(1..4).cover?(n)}}
  x.report {r.times {[1, 2, 3, 4].include?(n)}}
  x.report {r.times {case n;when 1,2,3,4;true;else;false;end}}
end
```

gives

```
       user     system      total        real
   0.093000   0.000000   0.093000 (  0.093600)
   0.141000   0.000000   0.141000 (  0.140400)
   0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.140400)
   0.265000   0.000000   0.265000 (  0.265200)
   0.063000   0.000000   0.063000 (  0.062400)
```

Comment: Interesting and surprising I agree. Why is the case-expression so fast? Would make an interesting SO question in itself...

Comment: I suppose it's because the first one are 2 expressions evaluated when positive n and the others are methods with their own overhead..
One could use a profiler to check.

Comment: Would be interesting to see if `n = 1` and `n = 4` makes a difference for the `case` statement.

Comment: did the test on another pc with MRI 2.3.0 64bit under W7, makes a very small difference (n=1 being slightly faster), in this version the first and last solution compete to be the fastest, most of the time it's the first, it confirms what I allready knew, always run your benchmarks on the system that you are going to use in production

Answer (score 1):

You can define your inclusive elements in an array and check if `n` is any of these with `include?`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].include?(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answers in other posts give answer to your question in the text, but here is my answer to your question in the title:

> Shorter ways to write this condition n != 1 || n != 2 || n != 3 || n !=4 in Ruby
>    n != 1 || n != 2 || n != 3 || n !=4 in Ruby

An expression: `true` would always be equivalent to that. And if you want to put that in a condition, the conceptually simplest is to not use any condition at all. Without a condition, just write whatever you wanted to do under that condition.