# erb defining a min and maximum

Tags: ruby, erb

I need to apply a conditional for a query only for results between two numbers (1 and 9).

I can't find a way of combining the greater than and less than operators and all I have the below which doesn't work.

Any help appreciated.

```
<% if @groups[location].size [1..9] %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Range#include?`

```
[2] pry(main)> (1..9).include? 2
=> true
```

And in your case

```
<% if (1..9).include?(@groups[location].size) %>
```

I'd prefer two conditions probably:

```
<% if @groups[location].size >= 1 && @groups[location].size <= 9 %>
```

EDIT:

Just as Mr. Sergio predicted I'd prefer [`Comparable#between?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Comparable.html#method-i-between-3F):

```
<% @groups[location].size.between?(1,9) %>
```

[`Range#cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F) is quite good as well:

```
<% if (1..9).cover?(@groups[location].size) %>
```

Worth reading: [What is the difference between `Range#include?` and `Range#cover?`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608935/what-is-the-difference-between-rangeinclude-and-rangecover)

Comment: I'm sure you'd prefer `Comparable#between?` if you remembered about it :)

Comment: Oh, and if we're talking ranges, `Range#cover?` is usually preferred in situations like this.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. @SergioTulentsev, obediently added your suggestions ;-)

Answer (score 5):

"(...) between two numbers (1 and 9)."

```
<% if @groups[location].size.between?(1, 9) %>
```