# Validate a string with Regex using Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I have to validate a range of strings: 00001 up to 01200

I want to make sure:

first digit is zero
second digit must be 0 or 1
third digit must be 0,1 or 2
last two numbers can be any digit

so far I have come up with this:

```
^(0|[0-1][0-2][0-9][0-9])$
```

but is not working, can you point me on the right direction?

Comment: Remove the `|`? It means 'or' so that you match either `0` or `[0-1][0-2][0-9][0-9]`. Though the problem isn't over yet. This regex accepts `01299` as well.

Comment: with a bit change `^0[0-1][0-2][0]{2}$`.

Comment: Just another solution, `("00001".."01200").grep(/^0[0-1][0-2][0]{2}$/).empty?` will help you to check if any string is falling in the range or not... also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Non-regex solution using [Range#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
("00001".."01200").include?("00002")
#=> true
```

Non-regex solution using [Range#cover?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F):

```
("00001".."01200").cover?("00002")
#=> true
```

Regex solution:

```
/^0([0-1][0-1][0-9]{2}|1200)$/
/^0([0-1][0-1][0-9]{2}|1200)$/ =~ "01200"
=> 0
 /^0([0-1][0-1][0-9]{2}|1200)$/ =~ "00300"
=> nil
```

Comment: Innovation ?? Hummm :)

Comment: @HamZa I have added a documentation link which should be adequate

Comment: @HamZa Range takes *numeric* literal or *character* literal or *number as a string*..

Comment: I'm not a ruby dev but I must admit that this is awesome.

Comment: @HamZa a reason why you need to add ruby to arsenal of languages

Comment: @HamZa the documentation of [`String#succ`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-succ) could help to understand why this works: *"Incrementing a digit always results in another digit"*, e.g. `"999".succ #=> "1000"`

Comment: Actually this doesn't work as expected for `('00001'..'01200').include?('00300') # => true`, but the string `'00300'` should be rejected, if I got the question properly.

Comment: The range includes all numbers from 1 to 1200 as strings with leadings zeros.

Comment: @toro2k The question was poorly worded, I believe the OP wants all values in the numeric range (making the regex answers actually not what he wants).

Comment: @bjhaid, how soon you forgot the [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507117/select-arrays-between-date-ranges-with-ruby) we had last month of [Range#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) vs [Range#cover?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F). Recall that the former defers to `Enumerable#include?` when, as here, the range endpoints are not numeric (or single-character strings), causing every element of the range to be checked. Here I suggest `(1..1200).include?(str.to_i)` +1. – Cary Swoveland 10 mins ago  edit

Comment: Some results for `include?` and `cover?` I found moderately interesting: `("00001".."300").include?("00300") => true`, `("0001".."300").include?("00300") => false`, 
`("00001".."1200").cover?("00300") => true`,  
`("1".."1200").cover?("00300") => false`, `("00001".."12").cover?("00300") => true`.

 => false`,

Comment: @CarySwoveland I doubt the answer with the `Range` is the perfect answer the OP wants as some of the comments showed which is why I included the regex solution too, however I would update my answer to include `cover` as advised. thanks

Comment: Yes, I agree that your regex is called for here.