# Can't iterate over Time objects in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time, google-calendar-api

I am writing an appointment form that will let the user choose a date. It will then take the date and check against a Google Calendar what time slots are available for that date within a range of 30 minutes time intervals from 10:00am to 5:00pm.

Within my Calendar class, I have an `available_times` method:

```
def available_times(appointment_date)
    appointment_date_events = calendar.events.select { |event| Date.parse(event.start_time) == appointment_date } 

    conflicts = appointment_date_events.map { |event| [Time.parse(event.start_time), Time.parse(event.end_time)] }
    results = resolve_time_conflicts(conflicts) 
end
```

This method takes a date and grabs the `start_time` and `end_time` for each event on that date. It then calls `resolve_time_conflicts(conflicts)`:

```
def resolve_time_conflicts(conflicts)
    start_time = Time.parse('10:00am') 
    available_times = [] 
    14.times do |interval_multiple|
      appointment_time = (start_time + interval_multiple * (30 * 60))  
      available_times << appointment_time unless conflicts.each{ |conflict| (conflict[0]..conflict[1]).include?(appointment_time)}  
    end
      available_times 
end
```

A 'Can't iterate over Time' error is being thrown when I attempt to iterate over the conflicts array. I tried to call `to_enum` on the conflicts array but am still getting the same error.

All of the other questions I saw on SO were referencing the `step` method, which doesn't seem applicable to this case.

**Update:**

```
Thanks @caryswoveland and @fivedigit. I combined both of your answers, which were very helpful for different aspects of my solution:

  def available_times(appointment_date)
    appointment_date_events = calendar.events.select { |event| Date.parse(event.start_time) == appointment_date } 

    conflicts = appointment_date_events.map { |event| DateTime.parse(event.start_time)..DateTime.parse(event.end_time) }
    results = resolve_time_conflicts(conflicts) 
  end

  def resolve_time_conflicts(conflicts)
    date = conflicts.first.first   
    start_time = DateTime.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, 10, 00).change(offset: date.zone) 
    available_times = [] 
    14.times do |interval_multiple|
      appointment_time = (start_time + ((interval_multiple * 30).minutes))
      available_times << appointment_time unless conflicts.any? { |conflict| conflict.cover?(appointment_time)}  
    end
      available_times 
  end
```

Comment: If you compute `conflicts` as an array of ranges `(Time.parse(event.start_time)..Time.parse(event.end_time))` (rather than as an array of arrays), you can write `...|conflict| conflict.cover?(...`.

Comment: Can you please show an example of one element of `calendar.events`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - Thanks, this made much more sense! Did you still want to see an element of calender.events after looking at my modifications above?

Comment: Only if you still need to know how to make the `appointment_time` date the same as the `conflicts` dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Exception**

@fivedigit has explained why the exception was raised.

**Other problems**

You need `any?` where you have `each`:

```
appointment_times = []
  #=> []
appointment = 4
  #=> 4
conflicts = [(1..3), (5..7)]
  #=> [1..3, 5..7]

appointment_times << 5 unless conflicts.each { |r| r.cover?(appointment) }
  #=> nil
appointment_times
  #=> []

appointment_times << 5 unless conflicts.any? { |r| r.include?(appointment) }
  #=> [5]
appointment_times
  #=> [5]
```

I suggest you covert `appointment_time` to a `Time` object, make `conflicts` and array of elements `[start_time, end_time]` and then compare `appointment_time` to the endpoints:

```
...unless conflicts.any?{ |start_time, end_time|
     start_time <= appointment_time && appointment_time <= end_time }
```

Aside: [Range#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) only looks at endpoints (as `Range#cover? does`) when the endpoints are "numeric". `Range#include?` need only look at endpoints when they are `Time` objects, but I don't know if Ruby regards `Time` objects as "numeric". I guess one could look at the source code. Anybody know offhand?

**Alternative approach**

I would like to suggest a different way to implement your method. I will do so with an example.

Suppose appointments were in blocks of 15 minutes, with the first block being 10:00am-10:15am and the last 4:45pm-5:00pm. (blocks could be shorter, of course, as small as 1 second in duration.)

Let 10:00am-10:15am be block 0, 10:15am-10:30am be block 1, and so on, until block 27, 4:45pm-5:00pm.

Next, express `conflicts` as an array of block ranges, given by `[start, end]`. Suppose there were appointments at:

```
10:45am-11:30am (blocks 3, 4 and 5)
 1:00pm- 1:30pm (blocks 12 and 13)
 2:15pm- 3:30pm (blocks 17, 18 and 19)
```

Then:

```
conflicts = [[3,5], [12,13], [17,19]]
```

You must write a method `reserved_blocks(appointment_date)` that returns `conflicts`.

The remaining code is as follows:

```
BLOCKS = 28
MINUTES = ["00", "15", "30", "45"]
BLOCK_TO_TIME = (BLOCKS-1).times.map { |i|
  "#{i<12 ? 10+i/4 : (i-8)/4}:#{MINUTES[i%4]}#{i<8 ? 'am' : 'pm'}" }
  #=> ["10:00am", "10:15am", "10:30am", "10:45am",
  #    "11:00am", "11:15am", "11:30am", "11:45am",
  #    "12:00pm", "12:15pm", "12:30pm", "12:45pm",
  #     "1:00pm",  "1:15pm",  "1:30pm",  "1:45pm",
  #     "2:00pm",  "2:15pm",  "2:30pm",  "2:45pm",
  #     "3:00pm",  "3:15pm",  "3:30pm",  "3:45pm",
  #     "4:00pm",  "4:15pm",  "4:30pm",  "4:45pm"]

def available_times(appointment_date)
  available = [*(0..BLOCKS-1)]-reserved_blocks(appointment_date)
                .flat_map { |s,e| (s..e).to_a }
  last = -2 # any value will do, can even remove statement
  test = false
  available.chunk { |b| (test=!test) if b > last+1; last = b; test }
           .map { |_,a| [BLOCK_TO_TIME[a.first], 
             (a.last < BLOCKS-1) ? BLOCK_TO_TIME[a.last+1] : "5:00pm"] }
end

def reserved_blocks(date) # stub for demonstration.
  [[3,5], [12,13], [17,19]]
end
```

Let's see what we get:

```
available_times("anything") 
  #=> [["10:00am", "10:45am"],
  #    ["11:30am",  "1:00pm"],
  #    [ "1:45pm",  "2:15pm"], 
  #    [ "3:00pm",  "5:00pm"]]
```

**Explanation**

Here is what's happening:

```
appointment_date = "anything" # dummy for demonstration

all_blocks = [*(0..BLOCKS-1)]
  #=> [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13,
  #    14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]
reserved_ranges = reserved_blocks(appointment_date)
  #=> [[3, 5], [12, 13], [17, 19]]
reserved = reserved_ranges.flat_map { |s,e| (s..e).to_a }
  #=> [3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 17, 18, 19]
available = ALL_BLOCKS - reserved
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 14, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]

last = -2
test = false
enum1 = available.chunk { |b| (test=!test) if b > last+1; last = b; test }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00000103063570>:each>
```

We can convert it to an array to see what values it would pass into the block if `map` did not follow:

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [[true, [0, 1, 2]],
  #    [false, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
  #    [true, [14, 15, 16]],
  #    [false, [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]]]
```

[Enumerable#chunk](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk) groups consecutive values of the enumerator. It does so by grouping on the value of `test` and flipping its value between `true` and `false` whenever a non-consecutive value is encountered.

```
enum2 = enum1.map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: (cont.)
      #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00000103063570>:each>:map>

enum2.to_a
  #=> [[true, [0, 1, 2]],
  #    [false, [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]],
  #    [true, [14, 15, 16]],
  #    [false, [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27]]]
```

You might think of `enum2` as a "compound" enumerator.

Lastly, we convert the second element of each value of `enum2` that is passed into the block (the block variable `a`, which equals `[0,1,2]` for the first element passed) to a range expressed as a 12-hour time. The first element of each value of `enum2` (`true` or `false`) is not used, so so I've replaced its block variable with an underscore. This provides the desired result:

```
enum2.each { |_,a|[BLOCK_TO_TIME[a.first], \
        (a.last < BLOCKS-1) ? BLOCK_TO_TIME[a.last+1] : "5:00pm"] }
  #=> [["10:00am", "10:45am"],
  #    ["11:30am",  "1:00pm"],
  #    [ "1:45pm",  "2:15pm"], 
  #    [ "3:00pm",  "5:00pm"]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Actually, appointment_time is a Time object. 

[3] pry(#<Calendar>)> appointment_time.class
=> Time

The issue I am having is how to get the appointment_time to be on the appointment_date - the same date at the conflicts.

Comment: Ah, I missed `start_time` in `appointment_time = (start_time +...` being a `Time` object, which makes `appointment_time` a `Time` object as well. I'll look at the date issue you raised.

Comment: `Range#include?` only in a few cases checks the `begin` and `end` values to determine whether a value is within the range. It does this for `Fixnums` and for strings of length 1. For other types, it iterates over the range using `Range#each`, which checks if the begin object responds to `succ`. This only works for discrete values, which `Time` is not. This also means that in this case, Ruby does not consider `Time` to be numeric.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @fivedigit. Note `Range#include?` checks endpoints for `Numeric` types, not just `Fixnums`: `(2.1..3.4).include?(2.8) #=> true` and of course `succ` isn't defined for `Float`. I too thought 1-character strings was another exemption, but I don't see that in the docs. I wondered why `include?` didn't just use endpoints, like `cover?`, until I came up with a [case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507117/select-arrays-between-date-ranges-with-ruby/21507252#21507252) where the two methods return different values for the range `('aa'..'zz')`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - sorry for the late reply since I just saw your updated alternative solution. Thanks for the solution, that is a very concise way of doing it!

Answer (score 6):

The issue comes from this bit:

```
(conflict[0]..conflict[1]).include?(appointment_time)
# TypeError: can't iterate from Time
```

You're creating a range of times and then checking if `appointment_time` falls within the range. This is what causes the error you're experiencing.

Instead of `include?`, you should use [`cover?`](http://devdocs.io/ruby/range#method-i-cover-3F):

```
(conflict[0]..conflict[1]).cover?(appointment_time)
```

This assumes that `conflict[0]` is the earliest time.

Comment: Thanks @fivedigity, I used cover? instead of include?, though I am not sure what the exact difference is :)

Comment: In the case of `Time` instances, `include?` attempts to iterate over the range, which in turn requires the objects in the range to implement a `succ` method, which returns an object's successor. For `Time`, this method is obsolete, so it throws a `TypeError`. `cover?` checks whether a value falls within the range using `begin <= value <= end`, which is comparison rather than iteration. Hence why it is required for the earliest time to be the begin of the range.

Comment: V, my apologies for an incorrect comment I made earlier, which I've deleted.

Comment: Actually, the example you posted demonstrated the actual root cause of the `TypeError` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your range from a range of times to a range of integers:

```
range = (conflict[0].to_i..conflict[1].to_i)
```

Then use the `===` operator as you used the `include?`:

```
conflict === appointment_time
```

EDIT: You can also obviously convert `appointment_time` to integer and still use `include?` since the range is now just an integer range.