# Check for integer in a collection of ranges

Tags: ruby, range

I'm trying to find the best way of determining in which range a given integer is.
Take this hash for example:

```
score_levels = {
  1 => {'name' => 'Beginner', 'range' => 0..50}, 
  2 => {'name' => 'Intermediate', 'range' => 51..70},
  3 => {'name' => 'Pro', 'range' => 71..85},
  4 => {'name' => 'Expert', 'range' => 86..96},
  5 => {'name' => 'Master', 'range' => 97..100}
}
```

I would like to run different logic given a score, something like:

```
case score
when score_levels[1]['range']
  level_counters[1] += 1
when score_levels[2]['range']
  level_counters[2] += 1
when score_levels[3]['range']
  level_counters[3] += 1
end
```

Is there a more generic way of doing it?
Maybe something in this spirit:

```
score_levels.each |key, val| {if val['range'].member?(score) then level_counters[key] += 1 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do ranges overlap and how many of them do you expect to have?

Comment: Ranges don't overlap. I guess something like 5 ranges, maybe a bit more

Comment: Good question. Though it may seem minor, readers appreciate you assigning a variable (`score_levels`) to your example's hash. All too often that is omitted, and even the hash's braces may be missing. As a general rule, when giving an example (a good thing), it's helpful to show your expected or desired output. Here, for example, you might have a small array of scores and show the levels you want them mapped to. Yes, it's obvious here, but it doesn't take much space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is.

```
level_counters[score_levels.find{|_, h| h["range"].include?(score)}.first] += 1
```

Comment: I see you used `include?` rather than `cover?` in case the range's end points are not numeric, but since the two are the same when the range is numeric, there's no loss of efficiency. What if `score` is not in any of the ranges?

Comment: @Jordan, that seems a bit harsh, but kudos for fessing up, something rarely seen in these parts.

Comment: Maybe `level_counters[level] += 1 if level = score_levels.find...`.

Comment: I've seen (or anyway perceived) a rash of terse, code-only answers lately and comments alone don't seem to be helping, so I'm giving downvotes a shot. This answer stuck out because it's a long, relatively complex one-liner (that gains nothing but inscrutability for being a one-liner) with no explanation. Thankfully it worked for OP but Ruby beginners reading this will find it challenging, to put it kindly. I am of course eager to retract downvotes for answers that are improved.

Comment: @Jordan, I favour ridicule, but only when I think the author may respond. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland I didn't think much about the choice between `include?` and `cover?`.

Comment: @sawa, it took me awhile to understand why `include?` is only equivalent to `cover?` when the range's end points are numeric or single-character strings. If interested, see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21507117/select-arrays-between-date-ranges-with-ruby/21507252#21507252).

Answer (score 4):

Since ranges do not overlap and seamlessly cover `0..100` - you do not need explicit ranges, but rather something like:

```
score_levels = [
  {id:1, name: 'Beginner', max_score:50},
  {id:2, name: 'Intermediate', max_score:70},
  {id:3, name: 'Pro', max_score:85},
  {id:4, name: 'Expert', max_score:96},
  {id:5, name:  'Master', max_score:100}
].sort_by{|v| v[:max_score]}
```

`sort_by` is optional, but left there to indicate that array should be sorted

And find itself (assumes that score does not exceed maximum and is always found)

```
level_counters[ score_levels.find{|v| score <= v[:max_score]}[:id] ] += 1
```

Comment: Note that the OP may want the array in the given form in order to have easy access to both ends of each range, so changing it to what you propose may be less convenient. Also, your solution its not as robust as ones that employ `range.include?`.  Suppose, for example, the score was `mm` and the ranges were `('a'...'z')` and `('aa'...'zz')`. The second range includes `mm`, but you'd choose the first, since `mm` <= `z` #=> true`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks, sure i meant `<=`, just a typo

Comment: yes, this solution is not as universal, but should be more performant because fixnum comparison is much cheaper

Comment: I wouldn't say "much cheaper", as you are examining one end point rather than two.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be looking up levels repeatedly and need to do it efficiently, consider constructing a separate hash:

```
score_to_level = score_levels.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  v['range'].each { |v| h[v] = k} }
  #=> {0=>1, 1=>1, 2=>1, 3=>1, 4=>1, 5=>1, 6=>1, 7=>1, 8=>1, 9=>1,
  #    10=>1,..., 91=>4,
  #    92=>4, 93=>4, 94=>4, 95=>4, 96=>4, 97=>5, 98=>5, 99=>5, 100=>5}
```

This of course assumes each range contains a finite number of values (not `(1.1..3.3)`, for example).